# Handing foreign keys relations with Django's rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Description:** I am creating a Django application for the first time and using the rest framework. My goal is to use the rest framework to test a post request for creating a new "Artwork" and adding it to my database. An artwork contains columns such as title, width, height, and etc. It also contains a column for a foreign key called "artist_id". This foreign key is linked to the primary key of my "Artist" table. In my artist table, I have the an artist_name column.

**My "Artwork" and "Artist" tables in Models.py:**

```
class Artwork(models.Model):
    idartwork = models.AutoField(
        db_column="idArtwork", primary_key=True
    )  # Field name made lowercase.
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created_month = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_created_year = models.TextField(
        blank=True, null=True
    )  # This field type is a guess.
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    width = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "artwork"

class Artist(models.Model):
    idartist = models.AutoField(
        db_column="idArtist", primary_key=True
    )  # Field name made lowercase.
    artist_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=40, db_collation="utf8_general_ci", blank=True, null=True
    )


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "artist"
```

**My problem:** In order to test the post request described in my description, my intuition is as following. First create a view that will update the artist table with the inputted name. Then, pass the primary key 'idArtist' and store it alongside the inputted artwork columns (title, width, etc.). **However**, I am not sure how to combine these two together. Currently, I have the views and serializers seperate as such:

Create artwork view (views.py):

```
class CreateArtworkView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ArtworkSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            title = serializer.data.get("title")
            date_created_month = serializer.data.get("date_created_month")
            date_created_year = serializer.data.get("date_created_year")
            comments = serializer.data.get("comments")
            width = serializer.data.get("width")
            height = serializer.data.get("height")

            artwork = Artwork(
                title=title,
                date_created_month=date_created_month,
                date_created_year=date_created_year,
                comments=comments,
                width=width,
                height=height,
            )

            artwork.save()

            return Response(
                ArtworkSerializer(artwork).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
```

Create artist view (views.py):

```
class CreateArtistView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            artist_name = serializer.data.get("artist_name")

            artist = Artist(artist_name=artist_name)

            artist.save()

            return Response(
                ArtworkSerializer(artist).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
```

Serializers.py:

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ["artist_name"]


class ArtworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Artwork
        fields = (
            "title",
            "date_created_month",
            "date_created_year",
            "comments",
            "width",
            "height",
            "artist",
        )
```

**What this looks like right now in the rest framework:**

Artwork (note: the artist drop down in a list of all the current artist_id's in the database. I want to be able to enter an artist name have a new artist_id created for an artwork):
[image]

Artist:
[image]

**Question Reiterated:**
How can I combine these two views together so it's done in one post request and the fk artist_id is updated based on what was inserted into the Artist table?

I tried the code (the code snippets provided) that does them seperately. It currently will update the database but they are not in sync. By 'in sync' I mean, I need to be able to recieve a post request of all the data at once (the html form in the provided pictures) and update the data base.